# Prove $\hom_R(R/I,N)\cong \{n\in N\mid\forall a\in I, an=0\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> Let $R$ a ring, $I$ a left ideal and $N$ an $R$-module. Prove
>   $$\hom_R(R/I,N)\cong \{n\in N \mid \forall a\in I, an=0\}$$
>   using the fact that there is an exact sequence
>   $$
> 0\to \hom_R(R/I,N)\to\hom_R(R,N)\to\hom_R(I,N) \, .
> $$

The only way I can think it could work is if the set $\{n\in N \mid \forall a\in I, an=0\}$ was a subgroup of $\hom_R(R,N)$ and it is exactly the image of the second homomorphism in the sequence.

Comment: It says the $R$-module homomorphism $\overline{\phi} : R/I \to N$ has to come from $\phi : R \to N, \phi(a) = a \bar{\phi}(1_{R/I})$ and $I \in \ker(\phi)$

Comment: @reuns sorry but that doesn't explain anything to me

Comment: It is the injection $hom_R(R/I,N) \to \{ \phi \in hom_R(R,N), I \in \ker(\phi)\} $ $\simeq \{  \phi \in hom_R(R,N), \phi(1_R) = n \in N, \phi(I) = nI = 0\}$

Comment: Ok, I get it now, thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Consider the short exact sequence:
$$0\longrightarrow I \overset{i}\longrightarrow R\overset{p}\longrightarrow R/I\longrightarrow 0$$
where  $i$ is the canonical injection of $I$  into $R$, and $p$ the canonical surjection from $R$ onto $R/I$.

Transform it by the left exact functor $\;\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}\Hom(-,N)$ and remember the isomorphism:
\begin{align}\Hom(R,N)&\overset{\sim}\longrightarrow N\\\varphi &\longmapsto \varphi(1)\end{align}

Comment: Functors are out of my league, so to speak

Comment: It's not a problem of category  theory. I guess you've seen what happens to a short exact sequence with Hom and tensor product?

Comment: Not at all. This question is just after a very short section on complexes and homology going over the definitions, with just some basic knowledge of modules. Regardless, the comment by reuns made me realise the answer.

Comment: Well, you get a left exact sequence $0\longrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(R/I,N)\longrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(R,N)\longrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(I,N)$. Just interpret what it means concretely.

Comment: The only thing I can discern that it tells me is that the second homomorphism is injective and hence if the set in question is the image of the homomorphism then it must be an isomorphism

Comment: It also says the image of the second homomorphism is the kernel of the third.

Comment: I am doing a similar exercise and thank you for your answer! It's very elegant. @Bernard