# Showing that $\mathrm{Hom}_R(R/I, M) \cong \mathrm{Ann}_I(M)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> $R$ is a ring (not necessarily commutative or with identity), $I$ is an ideal of $R$, and $M$ is an $R$-module. Also $\mathrm{Ann}_I(M) = \{m \in M \mid \forall i \in I \ im = 0\}$.
> I want to show that $\mathrm{Hom}_R(R/I, M) \cong \mathrm{Ann}_I(M)$.

I saw that this question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2460985), but it didn't really help me.

To make things easier I first tried to work with rings with identity.
Let's say we have $\phi \in \mathrm{Hom}_R(R/I, M)$ then $\phi(r + I) = \phi(r(1 + I)) = r\phi(1 + I)$ so $\phi$ is fully determined by $\phi(1 + I)$. But all this does is give me a map $\mathrm{Hom}_R(R/I, M) \to M$. I don't know how to show that $m \in \mathrm{Ann}_I(M)$. I'm not sure if this approach would work and even if it does, I don't know what I should do for rings without identity.

This is just an idea but I was thinking about starting from $\mathrm{Hom}_R(R, M)$, maybe finding a map $f: \mathrm{Hom}_R(R, M) \to M$ such that $\mathrm{Hom}_R(R, M)/\ker(f) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_R(R/I, M) \cong \mathrm{Im}(f) = \mathrm{Ann}_I(M)$ but I have made no progress on this.

Hints would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you might have the right idea because: hom$_R(R,M)\cong M$, think about why? You can think about hom$_R(R/I,M)$, as a subset of hom$_R(R,M)$, maybe the first isomorphism restricts to the isomorphism you want :)

Comment: Showing the map $\phi \mapsto \phi(1+I)$ is actually $\mathrm{Hom}_R(R/I, M) \to \mathrm{Ann}_I(M)$ is not hard ($i\phi(1+I) = \phi(i+I) = \phi(I) = 0$).  Showing it's an isomorphism is a bit more involved.

Comment: @BrianMoehring So let $\psi$ be the map you defined. Define $\psi^{-1}$ so that $\psi^{-1}(m) = \phi$ such that $\phi(1 + I)$ All I have to do is show that this is well-defined. (I think it's also easy to check that it is a homomorphism) Now if $\phi_1(1 + I) = \phi_2(1 + I) = m$ then $\forall r \in R \ \phi_1(r + I) = rm = \phi_2(r + I)$ so $\phi_1 = \phi_2$. Am I missing something? P.S I can't believe I forgot $I \subset R$ and forgot I can multiply things by $i$ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** this is only for unital rings as it explicitly uses $1 \in R$.

Define the map
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom} \DeclareMathOperator{\Ann}{Ann} 
\begin{array}{rccc} 
\alpha: & \Hom_R(R/I, M) & \longrightarrow & \Ann_I(M) \\
& \phi & \longmapsto & \phi(1+I)
\end{array}
$$
then show that $\alpha$ is

1. a well-defined homomorphism of abelian groups:
   $\quad \alpha(\phi_1 + \phi_2) = \alpha(\phi_1) + \alpha(\phi_2)$
2. surjective: $\quad\operatorname{Im} \alpha = \Ann_I(M)$
3. injective: $\quad\operatorname{Ker} \alpha = \{0\}$

Along with the hints in the comments, can you take it from here?

Comment: I tried finding an inverse for $\alpha$ instead of showing that it is a bijection, can you check my comment on the question?

Comment: I just noticed that in order to be able to define my map I actually need to prove that such $\phi$ exists so I should prove that $\alpha$ is onto anyway. But I'm gonna do it now.

Comment: Exactly. Also, showing that your inverse map is well-defined is exactly the same as showing that the original map is one-to-one.

Comment: Showing that $\alpha$ is injective is easy: $\alpha(\phi) = 0 = \phi(1 + I)$ so $\forall I \ \phi(r + I) = r(\phi(1 + I)) = 0$ so $\phi = 0$. To show that it is onto can't we just define a basic set map $f: R/I \to M$ such that $f(1 + I) = m$ and $f(r + I) = rm$? I think we can easily check that it is actually a module homomorphism. And if this all works, I still don't know what to do if $R$ isn't unital :_)

Comment: Injectivity looks good. For surjectivity, if you define $f$ directly (you keep changing names!) on $R/I$, then you have to check that it's well-defined since cosets of the ideal don't have unique representatives. However, the more standard way is to define $f: R \to M$ by $f(1) = m$, check that $I \subseteq \operatorname{Ker} f$ (why?), then appeal to the universal property of quotients: there exists a unique $\bar{f}: R/I \to M$ such that $\bar{f} \pi = f$, where $\pi: R \to R/I$ is the canonical projection.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach.

If $M$ is an $R$-module, and $N$ is a submodule of $M$, when we want to define a homomorphism with domain $M/N$, is sufficient define a homomorphism with domain $M$ whose kernel contains $N$. Explicitly, if $P$ is an $R$-module, and $\alpha \colon M \to P$ is a homomorphism with $N \subseteq \ker \alpha$, then we can define $\widetilde\alpha \colon M/N \to P$ via $\widetilde\alpha(m+N) := \alpha(m)$ for all $m \in M$. Sometimes, this is stated (in a very little enlightening way) as follows:

> If $P$ is an $R$-module, then *for every* homomorphism $\alpha \colon M \to P$ with $N \subseteq \ker \alpha$ *there exists a unique* homomorphism $\widetilde\alpha \colon M/N \to P$ such that $\widetilde\alpha \circ \pi = \alpha$, where $\pi \colon M \to M/N$ is the canonical quotient map.

Note that the words "*for every ... there exists a unique*" is a fancy way to say that the function
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Hom}_R(M/N,P) & \longrightarrow \{\alpha \in \operatorname{Hom}_R(M,P): N \subseteq \ker \alpha\} \\
\beta & \longmapsto \beta \circ \pi
\end{align*}
$$
is bijective.$^1$ Futhermore, one can check that the set in the right is a subgroup of $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,P)$, and that above function is a group homomorphism, hence a group isomorphism.

One more thing that we need to remember is the group isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M) \cong M$ that identifies $\alpha \in \operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M)$ with $\alpha(1) \in M$.

As an exercise, I will left to you to think about the following chain of group isomorphisms:
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Hom}_R(R/I,M) & \cong \{\alpha \in \operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M) : I \subseteq \ker \alpha\} \\
&= \{\alpha \in \operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M): \forall i \in I,\, \alpha(i)=0\} \\
&= \{\alpha \in \operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M): \forall i \in I,\, i\alpha(1)=0\} \\
&\cong \{m \in M : \forall i \in I,\, im=0\} \\
&= \operatorname{Ann}_I(M).
\end{align*}
$$

---

$^1$ A function $f \colon X \to Y$ is bijective if for every $y \in Y$ there exists a unique $x \in X$ such that $f(x)=y$, isn't?